# Need to export localgroupmember details ( Remote Desktop Users)

Tags: powershell

I am trying to pull the security group details in the Remote desktop users of each servers. But error is showing. Kindly assist me on this.

```
$Servers = Get-Content D:\HOST.txt
Foreach ($Server in $Servers)
{
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock {Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Remote Desktop Users"}  | Select PSComputerName,Name
}
```

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Try adding a foreach : Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock {Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Remote Desktop Users"}  | foreach {Select $_.PSComputerName,$_.Name}